# Nodetool behavior

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I have configured only three nodes, however nodetool sees one more on 
10.0.0.200 IP.

So, from where nodetool gets the information about this node?
How can I safely remove this node and split the information between 3.

```
 > /usr/bin/cassandra/nodetool status
    Datacenter: datacenter1
    =======================
    Status=Up/Down
    |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
    --  Address     Load       Owns   Host ID                               Token                                    Rack
    DL  10.0.0.200  ?          17.3%  8f2a4aab-0b83-454a-96b9-52ceff768892  17641649882960857202604498991049536772   rack1
    UN  10.0.0.1    85.73 KB   56.3%  159d6a4e-631b-4f20-8c9c-fe9bbba4aeac  113427455640312821154458202477256070485  rack1
    UN  10.0.0.11   32.94 MB   3.4%   2f93c222-5885-4141-a794-9913c68eb135  119167364151511659191387118070504026424  rack1
    UN  10.0.0.3    15.92 MB   23.0%  d6db9f0c-0adf-435d-ad38-a2c03f3b45b5  158286408450244808806328613098739900318  rack1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Always specify a keyspace when looking at the load column in `nodetool status` otherwise the data will not be accurate.

2) This depends mostly on your initial tokens (make sure they're equally spaced out) and on your data model (avoid hotspots / super wide rows).

#### Sequence of node destruction

`nodetool decomission` will get rid of the node if you need to kill it. It will stream the data to the other nodes in your cluster and then remove it from the ring.

If decomission fails 'nodetool remove' will remove a node thats already been terminated.

Finally if all else fails the jmx 'assassinate' mbean will remove a node from the ring. Only use if remove didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Here are the issues I have faced:
1) What keyspace means and where I can get it.

2) It should be performed on a server with the needed node, but this is what I get:
Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199': Connection refused

Also manipulations with this line didn't help
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"

All I want to say is that should be no node on this IP but nodetool shows and it exists.
Could you please advice?

Comment: Keyspace == Schema. in cqlsh run `describe keyspaces`

Comment: `Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199'` usually means your node is not up or you have a connectivity / network issue

Comment: Did you run decommission on the node you want to remove as I suggested in the answer ^^ ?

Comment: yes, I did that but it just hungs up and nothing happens

Comment: Did what exactly, decommission? This takes time as its streaming all the Data. Let it finish

Comment: Yes, but this is what I am getting at this node, as she should not even exist

Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199': Connection refused

Comment: That just means the cassandra process isnt running

Comment: That is the issue cassandra is not running on that server, however when I look on the status of it on another server I see that node is dead but contains data.

Also, I am trying to remove this node from another host but the task just hangs up:
sudo /usr/bin/cassandra/nodetool removenode 8f2a4aab-0b83-454a-96b9-52ceff768892

At the end I am unable to delete this node:
1) Decommission - can't connect
2) Remove - task hungs up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What DID help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662281/fully-removing-a-decommissioned-cassandra-node