# Decommission a Cassandra node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I just decommissioned one of my nodes in a Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes (all running Cassandra 3.3). One of the remaining nodes constantly is printing:

```
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-05-29 15:30:16,770 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /10.80.64.33 with status LEFT - alive false
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-05-29 15:30:17,770 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /10.80.64.33 with status LEFT - alive false
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-05-29 15:30:18,771 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /10.80.64.33 with status LEFT - alive false
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-05-29 15:30:19,771 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /10.80.64.33 with status LEFT - alive false
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-05-29 15:30:20,771 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /10.80.64.33 with status LEFT - alive false
```

in the logs for half a day or so, once a second. Any idea why? What this means?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I noticed both nodes are printing this message in the logs for the past 48 hours!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15687515/1849837 if it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies. I am using vnodes so I don't have to reassign the tokens automatically. The post is for Cassandra 1.0 which did not have vnodes.

also I'm using SimpleStrategy for my replication (I only have one DC) so I have not updated cassandra-topology.properties file. not sure this can be a reason, but so far even without the update to cassandra-topology.properties, everything works OK.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. How did you overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Its normal to have this message till 72 hours after the node is decomissioned.

More Details here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10371